# Merge 2 pandas data frames on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have 2 dataframes with one of them containing the prediction and actual values for the previous months. As shown below it has prediction from January and February. The values for Febuary are Null.

DF1

| Date | Key | Value | prediction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-1-21 | A | 33211 | 22123 |
| 1-1-21 | BA | 43231 | 32132 |
| 1-1-21 | C | 13431 | 43432 |
| 1-2-21 | A | Nan | 23421 |
| 1-2-21 | BA | Nan | 44443 |
| 1-2-21 | C | Nan | 32133 |

The second dataframe has date, key and value for February. I would like to merge them to form a new table with all actual values and a forecasts in one table

DF2

| Date | Key | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1-2-21 | A | 33212 |
| 1-2-21 | BA | 52121 |
| 1-2-21 | C | 23123 |

I want to merge the Values on the key and date into the first table. Final should look like this

| Date | Key | Value | prediction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-1-21 | A | 33211 | 22123 |
| 1-1-21 | BA | 43231 | 32132 |
| 1-1-21 | C | 13431 | 43432 |
| 1-2-21 | A | 33212 | 23421 |
| 1-2-21 | BA | 52121 | 44443 |
| 1-2-21 | C | 23123 | 32133 |

I tried `pd.merge` it creates a new column instead of join into one column and `pd.join` but it does a left join and drops some of the prediction data.
combine first simply appends to the data

Comment: what about pd.concat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's potentially a way to do it in one (albeit long) line:

```py
df1['Value'] = df1.apply(lambda row: row['Value'] if pd.notna(row['Value']) else df2[(df2['Date'] == row['Date']) & (df2['Key'] == row['Key'])].iloc[0]['Value'], axis=1)
```